# Interpreting and converting zone file data

Tags: networking, dns

I have a zone for a single TLD. I am trying to process the file data and convert it into JSON for other services that uses this data. Here's the first five lines of the file I have:

```
com.    900     in      soa     a.gtld-servers.net.     nstld.verisign-grs.com. 1612915221      1800    900     604800    86400
0-------------------------------------------------------------0.com.    172800  in      ns      ns1.domainit.com.
0-------------------------------------------------------------0.com.    172800  in      ns      ns2.domainit.com.
0-------------------------------------------------------------5.com.    172800  in      ns      fns.frogsmart.net.
0-------------------------------------------------------------5.com.    172800  in      ns      sns.frogsmart.net.
0-------------------------------------------------------------5.com.    172800  in      ns      tns.frogsmart.net.
```

Now I am not sure as how to interpret this file's data. I have looked at reference and example zone files at multiple places but, it does not resemble this format. One of the references can be found [here](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/12/html/Deployment_Guide/s2-bind-zone-examples.html). I just need some pointers on how to interpret each line. My understanding are the following:

1. The first value is the domain name
2. The next value is a number which, if I use the first line as header seems to be `900` (not sure what is)
3. The next value is `in` (not sure what this is)
4. The next value is `soa` which is `ns` (I think this means Start of Authority for domain is with Name server)
5. Lastly, the name server which, if I use the first line as header seems to `a.gtld-servers.net` (I think this is the primary SOA address)

Now the other properties (the first line I think indicates 10 properties) but these are not present in this file I am trying to process. That's all I could figure out so far and some help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First a warning: zonefiles can be big, especially `.com` one and converting that to JSON, especially if you intend to fully build the object in memory before using it, you might have trouble.

So you should start by asking yourselves if you really need all the data (for example as seen below what will you do with `SOA` content?) and if JSON is the most adequate representation, especially if not in a streaming way.

DNS data is explained in RFC 1034+1035.
More specifically §3.3.13 in RFC1035:

> 3.3.13. SOA RDATA format
>
> ```
> +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
> /                     MNAME                     /
> /                                               /
> +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
> /                     RNAME                     /
> +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
> |                    SERIAL                     |
> |                                               |
> +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
> |                    REFRESH                    |
> |                                               |
> +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
> |                     RETRY                     |
> |                                               |
> +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
> |                    EXPIRE                     |
> |                                               |
> +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
> |                    MINIMUM                    |
> |                                               |
> +--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+--+
> ```
>
> where:
>
> MNAME           The  of the name server that was the
> original or primary source of data for this zone.
>
> RNAME           A  which specifies the mailbox of the
> person responsible for this zone.
>
> SERIAL          The unsigned 32 bit version number of the original
> copy
> of the zone.  Zone transfers preserve this value.  This
> value wraps and should be compared using sequence space
> arithmetic.
>
> REFRESH         A 32 bit time interval before the zone should be
> refreshed.
>
> RETRY           A 32 bit time interval that should elapse before a
> failed refresh should be retried.
>
> EXPIRE          A 32 bit time value that specifies the upper limit on
> the time interval that can elapse before the zone is no
> longer authoritative.

But do not that the semantics have changed in later RFCs, the MINIMUM is now called the NEGATIVE TTL.

Also `IN` (case not significant) means `INternet` but all records will have that, consider it as a left over of past DNS experiments around classes that never worked.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was actually testing to see if I can save chunks of the zone file into smaller JSON files. The file I have is over 18 GB in size. I am using a stream with fixed pointers for extracting and processing contiguous chunks. But I still have one doubt: `172800` is this the SOA Serial Number? Because if this number changes (increments) then, that would mean an update of the DNS record. I also read a bit about Sequence Space Arithmetic as described in RFC 1035. Can I use the comparison criteria of these number for some sort of versioning?

Comment: In your example `172800` is the TTL of each record. The `SOA` record is only the first line, other lines are `NS` records. Each record has a TTL. As for the rest, your question is not clear, what are your goals? Where do you get zonefiles? The SOA serial will indeed change if the content of the zone changed, but maybe not on things you are interested with (ex: DNSSEC `RRSIG` records).But `.com` is such a big zone that obviously it will "always" get new domains or deleted domains,etc. which all changes the zonefile. The serial in your example is `1612915221` (it is often a Unix epoch,or a date)

Comment: @PatrickLevzek The information you provided was very helpful. A bit more on the context: I am working on a research project that wishes to determine patterns in newer domains that are being registered under `.com` TLD. The zone file are coming from official CZDS service of ICANN. I have a client that checks for new zone file availability and downloads newer version when available. Then it feeds the information to a search database (Typesense). Later batch queries are performed on the DB with various filters. The name server is an important one besides domain name. I was hoping to use more

Comment: information from this file. Anyways, thanks again for all your help.

Comment: Yes, `NS` records show nameservers authoritative on the domain. Note that there is a lot of research activity in patterns of domains. You may want to look at Nominet and SIDN Labs for a start, as well as various talks inside DNS OARC.